# How to use Brown corpus included in the NLTK toolkit to obtain the numbers and average numbers of words in specific grammar categories

Tags: python, nltk, part-of-speech

I have a text document and I need to obtain the numbers and average numbers of words in specific grammar categories (e.g., adverbs, adjectives, verbs, pronouns) using Brown corpus included in the [NLTK](http://nltk.org).

Comment: There seems to be plenty of examples of tagging out there. What have you tried?

Comment: I used Stanford NLP tagger. But since they are using Treebank corpus, I specifically look for a way that use Brown corpus for the training :)

Comment: The Brown corpus is already tagged. You can do it in one loop (except for the "average numbers", whatever that is) with a conditional frequency distribution. Look for an example in the nltk book.

Comment: I looked for the nltk book. Because I am too new to nltk I find difficulties to derive the aforementioned features. Could you please help me? :)